# OSL select function

Tags: scripting, color, osl

I try to run a shader with this function:

```
color albedo = select(steel,rust,pt1);
```

where variables: ***steel & rust*** are color and variable ***pt1*** is float(generated pattern). It gives me this error:

> function 'select' was not declared in this scope

So the question is : How to fix that? 
Also, are there any other methods to add one colorized pattern to another without mixing/burning their colors?